# how to get the id of the current user in asp.net from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am new to asp.net, I have a web form from where my customer could change his/her information, For that i am using update query. But for update i need the ID of that user. 
Can anyone help me in this? As i have tried querying to select ID on the basis of custname but no results.`

```
 SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.CommandText = "Select CustID from Customers where CustName = '" + Session["user"] + "'";
            id = Convert.ToInt32( cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

Correct me if im doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use ExecuteNonQuery if you don't expect a result. In this case you should use ExecuteScalar

```
 id = Convert.ToInt32( cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
```